# Do you have to run HLK against every target OS?

Tags: windows, driver, hardware, driver-signing

Since cross-signing is no longer available, I was going to try this HLK method for the old OSes (WinVista/7/8/8.1, server 2003, 2008, 2008r2, etc.. basically all those in that generation).  Does that mean I have to run against every os in every flavor (x64 / x86), that is a lot of OS installs and nowadays a pain since you can't get an updates.  When first creating it you simply tested on the new OS that was going to be released and had years or two in between.

Comment: I know this is slightly unrelated but on older OSs such as Windows 7 Windows update does not allow updates but you can find 2022 security updates for windows 7 on the microsoft databases, they just aren't released to windows

Comment: I am not one to understand the driver signing process but is it able to be done in command line?

Comment: I thought the SDK from microsoft had support for multiple OSs?

Comment: do you have a link for the updates?

Comment: @user19926715 - see https://knowledge.digicert.com/alerts/Kernel-Mode.html to find the cause of all the hassles/problems.